# Mysql - substracting value from previous day entring

Tags: mysql

i want to substract anem_reading value entered in session='morning' in both days , i.date=today and x.date yesterday  value display as a 'run', but error in sql code is thre

```
 SELECT x.date,

   i.anem_reading - (SELECT anem_reading
              FROM reg_data x
              WHERE date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
              AND x.(session=morning) = (i.session=morning)
              ORDER BY date 
              LIMIT 1) run FROM reg_data i;



  CREATE TABLE `reg_data` (
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `session` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` time default NULL,
  `temp_air` float NOT NULL,
  `rel_humid` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_5` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_20` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_30` float NOT NULL,
  `soil_temp_60` float NOT NULL,
  `air_pressure` float NOT NULL,
  `anem_reading` float NOT NULL,
  `dry_temp` float NOT NULL,
  `wet_temp` float NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`date`,`session`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Was `FLOAT` a deliberate choice?

Comment: I don't think `i.anem_reading - (select X) run FROM` anything is valid MySQL syntax.  Are you missing part of the query or have some parenthesis issue?  (maybe even just misssing `AS run`)?

Comment: @ebyrob yes this is myquery please give me help for godd query

Comment: Put `AS` in front of `run`.  It's possible that `AS` is optional, but it makes things readable (I certainly can't read it) and it is only optional in *SOME* cases, not all.  Also `x.date` in outer query is invalid.  `x` only exists in the sub query and can't be shared.  And `anem_reaing` without x or i prefix may be ambiguous and/or confusing.  This I've never seen done: `x.(session=morning)`, is that valid MySQL?  Did you read about doing it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
select a.dateToday, i.anem_reading - a.anem_reading
from              
(             
SELECT anem_reading
FROM reg_data x
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)              
  and session='morning'
  limit 1
) a,
    reg_data i
where i.session = 'morning'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same query translated for style (hopefully accurately):

```
SELECT 
  /**/x.date,/**/ -- this is a bug and should be fixed (i?)
  i.anem_reading - (
    SELECT x.anem_reading
    FROM reg_data AS x
    WHERE x.date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) -- relative to i.date?
      AND (x.session = x.morning) = (i.session = i.morning)
    ORDER BY x.date -- should be DESC?
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS run 
FROM reg_data AS i
;
```